# Getting historical options data using bloomberg into excel

Tags: excel, finance, bloomberg, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to get the option price from 11/8/17 to 14/8/17 with the 12/20/19 expiration for the 4200 put on the SX5E Index.

I wrote the code below but it gives me an N/A Invalid Field error.

```
=BDH("SX5E 12/20/19 P4200 Index",11/8/2017,14/8/2017)
```

I tried changing the dates around and adding a 0 before the 8 but it does not work and the security name is valid as I searched it on bloomberg and fixed an error that said it was invalid from before.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a field. Say you want to retrieve the daily price, you can use `PX_LAST` for example:

```
=BDH("SX5E 12/20/19 P4200 Index", "PX_LAST", 20170811, 20170814)
```

Also note that I'm not sure it will work with the date format you are using, I've changed it to yyyymmdd. Alternatively you can use references to other cells containing the dates you need.

Comment: Do you know how I could just get it for one day? Not a range. It gives me an error if I only do it for one day right now

Comment: `=BDH("SX5E 12/20/19 P4200 Index", "PX_LAST", 20170811, 20170811)` - although it may return an error if the security did not trade on that day. In that case you may need to add a few overrides: `=BDH("SX5E 12/20/19 P4200 Index", "PX_LAST", 20170811, 20170811. "Days=A,Fill=P")`

Comment: Also note that you can ask these questions to Bloomberg support team by typing F1 twice on your terminal.